# How to test HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed in Java webapp?

Tags: java, session, tomcat

How might a person simulate firing the HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed object in a session listener?

Is just setting the Tomcat session timeout to 1 and then waiting the only way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`HttpSession.invalidate()`](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate()). Alternatively, you can call [`setMaxInactiveInterval()`](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int)) with a small number (i.e. 1). This is less reliable as there's no guarantee as to when Tomcat will destroy the session.